# Data disappeared from my HDD

Tags: windows

I find myself in a very unpleasant situation, this morning, when I turned on the PC, I found myself with my HDD, where games, various files, photos and more are installed, with this capacity and inside a file "EFI", I would like to know what happened to my data and how to recover it.
Thanks in advance (I used Google Translate)

[image]

Comment: It may be that you signed on with a temporary user profile. Use the regular shut down procedure from the Start Menu. Shut down normally, wait 10 seconds, start up and be certain you are signing on as yourself with your correct password. The documents will likely come back.

Comment: Not even this works

Comment: Prepare to restore your backups.

Comment: Your D partition was reformatted as FAT. Try a recovery product such [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the partition table. Do not write or do anything to D.

Comment: I would not use the drive if recovery programs do not work. You may need a local recovery agency

Comment: Did you play with system restore / installation media / utilities recently? You may have put a ~500MB "_EFI System Partition_" on your 1TB disk (based on the report of a folder named "EFI"). It's possible that either all of, or the first ~500MB of your data partition has been overwritten. The easiest way to recovery might be via your backups...

Answer (score -1):

Some suggestions:

- When you start experimenting on this drive, first make a sector by sector copy on another
- Try to look at the contents of the HDD in antoher system by connecting it through USB
- Does running Piriform "Recuva" reveal your files?
  drive. You can find various packages that can do that for you.
- When you have your copy: format the drive to the same filingsystem

Good luck!